# JavaFx Error when passing array in root.getChildren().add()

Tags: arrays, exception, javafx, duplicates, children

in the code below when i use only the line 54 ( line 55 comment ) , it works fine . But when i execute with line 55 in action , i get that error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Pane@16d2d0b

```
    Image white = new Image("/javafxapplication1/white.png");
    ImageView whiteView = new ImageView(white);

    Image red = new Image("/javafxapplication1/red.png");
    ImageView redView = new ImageView(red);

    ImageView[] whiteArray = new ImageView[3];
    ImageView[] redArray = new ImageView[3];

    //the points of columns int the board map
    int[][] whitepoints={{54,27},{235,27},{417,27}};
    int[][] redpoints={{145,27},{325,27},{507,27}};

            whiteArray[0]=whiteView;
            whiteArray[0].setLayoutX(whitepoints[0][0]);
            whiteArray[0].setLayoutY(whitepoints[0][1]);

            whiteArray[1]=whiteView;
            whiteArray[1].setLayoutX(whitepoints[1][0]);
            whiteArray[1].setLayoutY(whitepoints[1][1]);

    Pane root = new Pane();

    imgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
    imgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(primaryStage.heightProperty());
    root.getChildren().add(imgView);

    54!!! root.getChildren().add(whiteArray[0]);
    55!!! root.getChildren().add(whiteArray[1]);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Backgammon!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: you are adding the same `ImageView` to `root` twice.

Comment: rather confused with the use of ImageView[] , that this operates as a classic array ... !?

Comment: Well, yeah, what else would it be? The point is that `whiteArray[0]` and `whiteArray[1]` refer to the very same object.

Comment: nahh that meaning that it doesnt behaves like arrays. I am searching for how to declare multiple objects to array , for  saying `for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ whiteArray[i].setImage(image)}`

Comment: Of course it behaves like an array. But you are putting the same reference into two different slots in the array. Draw a memory diagram.

Comment: Or just think of it like this. Only looking at `white` (i.e. ignore `red`, `redView` and `redArray` for now), you *only ever create one `ImageView` instance* (you only call `new ImageView(...)` once). So clearly you must be trying to put the same instance of `ImageView` in the scene graph twice.

Comment: yeaaah , i got this . separated. `for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            
                whiteArray[i]= new ImageView(white);
                whiteArray[i].setLayoutX(whitepoints[i][0]);
                whiteArray[i].setLayoutY(whitepoints[i][1]);
        }`

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `whiteArray[0]` and `whiteArray[1]` both refer to the same instance of `ImageView` (the one you previously called `whiteView`). You can't add the same `ImageView` to the scene graph twice.

I think what you are trying to do is share the same `Image` between two different `ImageView`s:

```
Image white = new Image("/javafxapplication1/white.png");

Image red = new Image("/javafxapplication1/red.png");

// maybe the same problem with this in code you haven't shown???
ImageView redView = new ImageView(red);

ImageView[] whiteArray = new ImageView[3];
ImageView[] redArray = new ImageView[3];

//the points of columns int the board map
int[][] whitepoints={{54,27},{235,27},{417,27}};
int[][] redpoints={{145,27},{325,27},{507,27}};

whiteArray[0]=new ImageView(white);
whiteArray[0].setLayoutX(whitepoints[0][0]);
whiteArray[0].setLayoutY(whitepoints[0][1]);

whiteArray[1]=new ImageView(white);
whiteArray[1].setLayoutX(whitepoints[1][0]);
whiteArray[1].setLayoutY(whitepoints[1][1]);

Pane root = new Pane();

imgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
imgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(primaryStage.heightProperty());
root.getChildren().add(imgView);

root.getChildren().add(whiteArray[0]);
root.getChildren().add(whiteArray[1]);
```